# Finding the number of occurrences of a number in a sorted array with O(log(N)) in C?

Tags: c, binary-search

If i have a sorted array `arr[]` conatains `n` eleemnts, how can I find the number of occurrences of a certain number `key` with the complexity of O(logn)?

For example:
for

```
int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 7};
int n = 8;
int key = 6;
int first, last;
```

I will get `3`.

My approach to the problem was by doing two binary searches, one searches for the index of first occurrence of `key`, saving the result in `int first`. And another one searches for the index of the last occurrence of `key`, saving the result in `last`. Then the only thing left to do is to return
`last - first + 1`.

But when I started to code the problem, I came into a problem, I couldnt calculate `last` what resulted strange results. I have been trying to debug my code but with no success, Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

int ex2(int*, int, int);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 11, 14, 22};
    printf("%d", ex2(arr, 11, 6));
    return 0;
}

int ex2(int* a, int n, int x)
{
    int low = 0, high = n - 1, mid, first = 0, last = 0;
    // bin first
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (a[mid] == x)
        {
            if (mid - 1 < low || a[mid - 1] < x)
            {
                first = mid;
                break;
            }
            else
                high = mid - 1;
        }
        if (a[mid] < x)
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            high = mid - 1;
    }
    // bin last
    low = 0;
    high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (a[mid] == x)
        {
            if (mid + 1 > high|| a[mid + 1] > x)
            {
                last = mid;
                break;
            }
            else
                low = mid + 1;
        }
        if (a[mid] < x)
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            high = mid - 1;
    }
    return last - first + 1;

}
```

When I run it for:

```
    int arr[] = {1, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 11, 14, 22};
    printf("%d", ex2(arr, 11, 6));
```

I get -1 (Becuase `last` is still `0` unlike `first` which holds the right value of `2` - > 0 - 2 + 1 = -1).
When I sould get 3 (6 appears 3 times).

Comment: You’re forgetting to set `first`/`last` when the end of the loop is reached without ever triggering the `mid - 1 < low || a[mid - 1] < x`/`mid + 1 > high || a[mid + 1] > x` condition, i.e. when `low == high` as a result of `low = mid + 1` or `high = mid - 1`. (Also, you can start the second part with `low = first` for efficiency.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `!(mid - 1 < low)` implies `a[mid - 1]` is in bounds.

Comment: @EricPostpischil mid - 1 < low and mid + 1 > high are for checking if i am not out of the array bounds

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am assuming x will always be in the array

Comment: Youre right, ignore the rest of my code and only notice the part where I am trying to find the last occurrence of x, do you understand my intentions there?

Comment: YahavB, Minor tip: rather than coding the `8` with potential it is not the right value, use `int n = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `if (a[mid] < x)` to `else if (a[mid] < x)` both places it appears.

Otherwise, in the case where `a[mid] == x` and you set `low` (in the first search) or `high` (in the second search), the code then falls through to this test of `a[mid] < x` and sets the other bound, incorrectly. Inserting the `else` excludes that.